# switching jquery tabs in code behind(C#)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have five div tags(jquery tabs) in my aspx page...Inside the second div(tab) i have a button. onclick of that buttton the second div(tab) should be switched..instead of that the first tab is coming.. How can i switch the tab in code behind(Inside button onclick event)...

Comment: Would be very nice to see your code to understand the problem.

Comment: see my code in this page.  http://www.jqueryhelp.com/viewtopic.php?p=9053#9053

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the client code instead of in the code behind, but if you really need to do  it on the code behind, you can pass a int number (ie: when you must show the first tab the int value must be 0).

Then with a script you show the tab with :eq(@number@).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The [`tabs`](http://www.stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs/) function only takes 2 arguments:

```
$.fn.tabs = function(initial, settings)
```

But you're calling the function with 3 arguments:

```
string _tabSelected = "$(\"#tabs\").tabs('option', 'selected', 6);";
```

You should try the following instead:

```
string _tabSelected = "$(\"#tabs\").tabs(nr_of_active_tab);";
```

...where `nr_of_active_tab` should be self-explanatory.

PS: [This](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/switching-jquery-tabs-in-code-behind-c) is the correct link to your forum post over at jqueryhelp.com